# Use MediaCapture class in Desktop app

Tags: windows-8

I'm trying to capture an image from the webcam in a desktop app in Windows 8 using the MediaCapture class

Is it possible to use the MediaCapture class in a Desktop app?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/desktop/windows.media.capture.mediacapture

At the bottom it is shown that Desktop app is supported, but there is no example code using C++/C#

Can someone provide me some example code if this is possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had some success using the Win8 API (Windows.Management.Deployment.PackageManager) in a command line app, but I don't have any definitive settings at the moment so that it's clean and reproducable ;)

I remember [this article](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/using-winrt-apis-from-desktop-applications) helping me along quite nicely. It is a bit outdated but the principle remains the same:

- set 'Windows Store App support' to true
- add the TargetPlatformVersion tag to the project file
- force the project to compile/link against Windows.winmd (iirc one needs to add the folder  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\References\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\" to the include path, the /FU switch didn't work for me)

Comment: I think the article has been updated since you last used it, but thanks, great article!

Answer (score 0):

There you go

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/eternalcoding/archive/2013/10/29/how-to-use-specific-winrt-api-from-desktop-apps-capturing-a-photo-using-your-webcam-into-a-wpf-app.aspx

This is perhaps what you need!